# Why is the "src" attribute short for "URL"?

Tags: html, url

I'm a newbie to HTML. It's always hard to remember shorthand if I don't know the full name.

Why `src` is the shorthand for URL? Could anyone list the full name for `src`?

Comment: It's "source", or perhaps "resource"…

Answer (score 4):

It is an abbreviation for [*source*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/source):

> A place, person, or thing from which something originates or can be obtained.